# Visual studio muliline edit jump to end of individual words?

Tags: visual-studio

When I type `SHIFT+CTRL+RIGHT`, it jumps to the end of the next word and adds it to the selection.

With PyCharm, when I have multiple line selected, it will be smart and jump a different number of characters depending on the length of the word on the selected line:

[image]

However, on Visual Studio, it jumps to match the longest word in the selection. I can't imagine in what case this is useful.

[image]

**Is there a way to have the jump matches the length of the word on the line, like in the first example?**

I am using Visual Studio Community Version 16.4.2